# Not inserting the message into table

Tags: php, mysql

In my code below, it should clear the table Banner, which it does, then insert a message into it, which it does not
This is my code, thanks

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db("induadmi_db");
if($_POST['submit']){
    $bannermsg = $_POST['newBanner'];
mysql_query("TRUNCATE `Banner`");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Banner` SET Message='$bannermsg'");
}
?>
<html>
     <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" id="newBanner" name="newBanner' placeholder="Enter Message"/>
             <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the error I get by the way:

> Notice: Undefined index: newBanner in
>   /home/induadmi/public_html/por/newbanner.php on line 5

Comment: This is the error I get by the way: Notice: Undefined index: newBanner in /home/induadmi/public_html/por/newbanner.php on line 5

Answer (score 4):

Here is Your Error In HTML

```
<html>
         <body>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="text" id="newBanner" name="newBanner" placeholder="Enter Message"/>
                 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

`name="newBanner'` is Error `name="newBanner"`

Comment: @Sam Than You Must Accept answer

Answer (score 1):

your error means `$_POST['newBanner']` has not been defined. so put `$bannermsg = $_POST['newBanner'];` inside `if($_POST['submit']){` condition

try like this by checking whether `$_POST` exixts

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db("induadmi_db");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $bannermsg = $_POST['newBanner'];
     mysql_query("TRUNCATE `Banner`");
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Banner` SET Message='$bannermsg'");
}
?>
```

Comment: Did it, same problem though

Comment: Mr.Downvoter could you please explain whats the reason for downvote ?

Comment: Wasn't me, I don't have enough points, someone just went and downvoted everything here

Comment: @Sam yeah i know.LOL. I just posted it to ask to person who downvoted

Comment: @krishna: Down vote might be for 2 reasons. First: The variable `$bannermsg` was defined proper but you are advising to move it into `if` block. Second: Error was not with that. (BTW: I didn't DV)

Comment: @Ravinder if the variable `$bannermsg` was outside the `if block` it will show error when the page loads for first time as there will be no `POST` variables

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
        error_reporting(-1);
        mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
        mysql_select_db("induadmi_db");
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $bannermsg = $_POST['newBanner'];
             mysql_query("TRUNCATE `Banner`");
             mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Banner` SET Message='$bannermsg'");
        }
        ?>



    <html>
     <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" id="newBanner" name="newBanner" placeholder="Enter Message"/>
             <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not close the quotes properly on your `<form>` ..

```
 name="newBanner' place
                ^----------
```

That is why you were getting the `Undefined:index` Notice.. Always make use of the `isset` construct.

Also...Your `TRUNCATE` syntax is wrong..

It should be

```
mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `Banner`");
```

###The fixed code..

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
error_reporting(-1);
mysql_connect('localhost', 'induadmi_main', '$admiNiNd/U');
mysql_select_db("induadmi_db");
$bannermsg = $_POST['newBanner'];

    mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `Banner`");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Banner` SET Message='$bannermsg'");
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" id="newBanner" name="newBanner" placeholder="Enter Message"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, **Prepared Statements** of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extension should be used to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: This the best answer provided here.It should be an accepted answer and should have high votes.But its vice-verse.I don't know whats wrong going here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the results of mysql_query to see if the call succeeded, and if it didn't, to check mysql_error to see what the error is.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php